# Rails Rspec test Slack::Notifier

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback, rubygems, rspec-rails

I have my own gem (just for learning). So, I have my test app which uses my gem. In my app I created initializer file for add custom callback for on of my gem model.

Something like this:

```
#my_app/confing/initializers/my_nagios.rb
MyNagios::Check.class_eval do
 after_save :send_slack_notification

 private

 def send_slack_notification
    ...
    @notifier ||= Slack::Notifier.new "..."
    ...
    @notifier.ping "..."
```

And for now I want to create Rspec test for this custom callback.

I try something like this:

```
describe MyNagios::Check do
  let(:slack_notifier)  { double(Slack::Notifier) }

  it 'should send notification' do
    ... some actions ...
    expect(slack_notifier).to receive(:ping).with('test') # 'test' just for now, it will be replaced
```

But I receiving an error:

```
   (Double Slack::Notifier).ping("test")
       expected: 1 time with arguments: ("test")
       received: 0 times
```

Should I use `double` for `Slack::Notifier` or not? What is wrong in my test?

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things that might help:

1. Your double isn't being used, unless you are assigning the `@notifier` variable somewhere that you haven't shown. The instance of `Slack::Notifier.new` in `config/initializers/my_nagios.rb` is what is receiving the ping. You need to set it up so that you can pass your `slack_notifier` double into the MyNagios instance.
2. The expectation needs to be set up *before* the save happens, so if the ping is supposed to happen during '...some actions...' then you need to move your expect above this point.

Putting it all together, you should get something like this:

```
class MyNagios
  def initialize(slack_notifier)
    @slack_notifier = slack_notifier
    #...
  end
end

# test
it 'should send notification' do
  #... some actions ...
  expect(slack_notifier).to receive(:ping).with('test')
  MyNagios.new(slack_notifier).save
end
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: That said, you would probably find it a lot easier to write these tests in the gem itself rather than in an app _using_ the gem.

Comment: Thanks for help. Well, not the most elegant solution, but I`m use for now something like this: `expect_any_instance_of(Slack::Notifier).to receive(:ping).with('...').and_return(true)`